# How to show image with js template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, image

I want to show image as follow, but seem it not working. data name and address show, but image not show. Please see my code snippet.

```js
    var JSONObject = [{
                name: 'Nyonya',
                user_image: '~/Content/images/user1.png',
                address: '199 Grand Street New York, NY 10013, United States'
            }, {
                name: 'Mulberry Project',
                user_image: '~/Content/images/user2.png',
                address: '149 Mulberry Street New York, NY 10013, United States'
            }, {
                name: 'Sweet & Vicious',
                user_image: '~/Content/images/user3.png',
                address: '5 Spring Street New York, NY 10012, United States'
            }], template = $.trim($('#jstemplate').html());

            var $ct = $('.slider');
            $.each(JSONObject, function (i, v) {
                var temp = template.replace(/{{name}}/ig, v.name)
                                    .replace(/{{address}}/ig, v.address)
                                    .replace(/{{user_image}}/ig, v.user_image);
                $(temp).hide().appendTo($ct);
            });
```

```html
 <div class="slider">
                        <script id="jstemplate" type="js/template">
                            <div class="items text-center">
                                    <div class="wow scaleIn">
                                        <img src="~/Content/images/home/logo.png" />
                                        <img src="{{user_image}}" />
                                    </div>
                                    <h2>{{name}}</h2>   
                                    <p>{{address}}</p> 
                            </div>
                        </script>
                    </div>
```

Can you tell me what wrong in here or give me some mistake ? Thank you so much.

Comment: There is no JSON in your question: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: `'~/Content/images/user1.png'` looks like the kind of URL that gets expanded, server side, by ASP.NET. Shoving it into client side JavaScript might be bypassing that expansion code. Use the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Element inspector. Can you see the `<img>` element added by JS? Does the `src` attribute resolve to an image or a 404 when you right click and open it in a new tab?

Comment: Dear @Quentin , in developer tool , i see `<img src="{{user_image}}">` , not show same `<img src="~/Content/images/user3.png">`

Comment: You appear to be looking at the raw template and not the elements that `appendTo($ct);` appended.

Comment: Are you sure ?. Can you check it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `hide()` is causing the problem. It is creating the html element from `$(temp)` but it is hiding it, so you can't see it. Just do

```
$(temp).appendTo($ct);
```

Comment: Dear @Adi Levin, `name` and `address` is show, but `image` not show , please view clearly . Thank you.

Comment: The `<img>` element exists. When I change the image URL to a valid one, this works. Check your image URLs.

Comment: Oh, yes , that's it . Thank you so much. I forget it.